# color picker and design стилизация и ключи рендера

Tags: css, reactjs

[image: мой color picker]

Как мне сменить цвет стрелочек и текста (на изображении отмечено стрелками) и как мне сместить нижний блок, который подчеркнут (сместить нужно именно строку где выбран формат, сам цвет и его прозрачность)? Так же у меня проблема с ключами, дает такую ошибку:  **Encountered two children with the same key, `panel-[object Object]`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.** Вот фото ошибки [image: ошибка]
Вот мой код:

```
<ColorPicker
        onOpenChange={()=>setActive((n)=>!n)} 
        styles={{popup:{color:'#fff'},popupOverlayInner:{backgroundColor:'#1f2433',boxShadow:'0 2px 4px #0006',color:'#fff',width: 468 + 44}}} style={{backgroundColor:'transparent',border:'none', outline:'none',color:'#fff'}}
        value={hexString} onChange={setColorHex} onChangeComplete={(value)=>endColorFunc(value)}
        presets={[
          {
            label: <p style={{color:'#fff'}} id='recommend'>Рекомендованные</p>,
            colors: colors,
          },
          {
            label: <p style={{color:'#fff'}} id='recent'>Недавние</p>,
            colors: recentColors
          },
        ]}
        panelRender={(_, { components: { Picker, Presets } }) => (
          <div
            className={styles.panel}
            style={{
              display: 'flex',
              width: 488,
            }}
          >
            <div
            key={Math.random()}
              style={{
                flex: 1,
              }}
            >
              <Presets key={Math.random()} />
            </div>
            <Divider
              type="vertical"
              style={{
                height: 'auto',
              }}
            />
            <div
            key={Math.random()}
              style={{
                width: 234,
                marginTop:29,
                color:'#fff'
              }}
            >
              <Picker key={Math.random()}/>
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      />
```

Comment: Ошибка явно не из этого куска кода

Comment: SwaD, пересмотрите, пожалуйста, вопрос, я его поправил, добавил фотографию ошибки